# After macbook restart no tmux commands can be found in .tmux.conf?

Tags: tmux, macos-mojave

(tmux newbie)

macOS mojave

tmux 3.1b

Has this happened to anyone else?

This problem occurs when sourcing the tmux conf.

Also, should I post the tmux conf file?

```
home/.tmux.conf:17: command not found: set-option
home/.tmux.conf:18: command not found: set-option
home/.tmux.conf:33: command not found: unbind
home/.tmux.conf:39: command not found: setw
home/.tmux.conf:49: command not found: bind
home/.tmux.conf:50: command not found: bind
home/.tmux.conf:56: command not found: bind
home/.tmux.conf:59: command not found: bind
home/.tmux.conf:62: command not found: bind
home/.tmux.conf:65: command not found: bind
home/.tmux.conf:65: command not found: split-window
home/.tmux.conf:68: command not found: bind
...
...
```

Comment: This is what `zsh` says when one tells it to source `.tmux.conf`. Did you tell your `zsh` to source `.tmux.conf`?

Comment: yes, that is correct. none of my commands in the .tmux.conf are registered it seems.

Comment: `.tmux.conf` is supposed to be read by `tmux`, not by `zsh`. `tmux` should read it automatically, [unless …](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66607/108618)

Comment: Oh now I figured it out. A couple of errors occured that were based on my tmux conf. This made me reload the tmux conf with the wrong command and this made me super confused. I was using the wrong source command in zsh to reload the tmux.conf but `source` instead of `source-file`. No everything works it seems. Embarassing... Thanks Kamil !!!

Comment: It looks more like `source ~/.tmux.conf` (where `source` is a builtin in `zsh`) instead of `tmux source ~/.tmux.conf` (which *is* equivalent to `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`). Note I did not write a proper answer because it's not clear to me what really happened.

Comment: yeah, i was a bit confussed. I wrote my solution in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a BAD question because I was confussed when I wrote it.
2. I had missunderstood how one reloads the tmux config. The correct way of doing this is
   by writing `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`